# How can I identify a Route by its path

Tags: angular, angular8, angular9

I'm working with **Angular 8.2.4**,

While I'm getting ActivatedRoute, I want to identify the activated children of the current Route is it v1 or v2.

I managed to get the first children activated Route:

```
let currentRoute = this.route.snapshot.children[0];
```

But I have to know if it is v1 or v2 or neither v1 nor v2 ? => I want to be precise.

I think that's can be a good feature for next Angular version that we add name property in routes definition and we add a certain name in ActivatedRoute also.

But Now, How am I going to make the difference between the two children route ?

**app-routing:**

```
routes = {
            path: '',
            pathMatch: 'full',
            redirectTo: 'home',
        },
        {
            path: 'new',
            children: [
                {
                    path: 'v1',
                    pathMatch: 'full',
                    component: newComponent,
                },
                {
                    path: 'v2',
                    pathMatch: 'full',
                    component: new2Component,
                }
            ],
        };
```

**AppComponent.ts:**

```
constructor(
    private readonly route: ActivatedRoute,
) {
    let currentRoute = this.route.snapshot.children[0];
    if (currentRoute is v1){
        //treatment.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find the segment you are looking.

```js
const isv1 = this.route.snapshot.url.find((seg) => seg.path === 'v1')
```